# Добавление связанных объектов в модель

Tags: django, model

Столкнулся с проблемой при добавлении связных объектов в модель. Все делаю по документации, но вылазит ошибка.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # order model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350, default=None, verbose_name='Имя')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Номер телефона', default='')
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,
                                decimal_places=2,
                                default=None,
                                verbose_name='Итого')
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Исполнен')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
        product = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                       default=None, verbose_name='Товар')
```

мои манипуляции:

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST['name']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        order = Order(name=name,
                      phone_number=phone,
                      total=Decimal(cart.total_price))
        order.save()
        item_id = cart.items_list[0]['product_id']
        print(item_id)
        order_item = OrderItem(product_id=item_id)
        order_item.save()
        order.orderitem_set.add(order_item)
        order.save()

        return HttpResponse('')
```

выдает ошибку

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: momshop_orderitem.order_id
```

сам заказ сохраняет с номером телефона, именем и тоталом. Однако добавление связных объектов не удается. Буду признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в создании объекта One-to-one. Во первых, неправильно добавлял объект, вместо:

```
order_item = OrderItem(product_id=item_id)
order_item.save()
```

нужно:

```
 item = Products.objects.get(id=item_id)
 order_item = OrderItem(product=item, order=order)
```

во вторых, Django не понимал к какому заказу относится этот объект:

```
 item = Products.objects.get(id=item_id)
 order_item = OrderItem(product=item, order=order)
```

**order=order**

Исправленный фрагмент файла view(мои манипуляции):

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST['name']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        order = Order(name=name,
                  phone_number=phone,
                  total=Decimal(cart.total_price))
        order.save()
        item_id = cart.items_list[0]['product_id']
        item = Products.objects.get(id=item_id)
        order_item = OrderItem(product=item, order=order)

        order_item.save()

        return HttpResponse('')
```